# Rails custom consumer oauth strategy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, magento, oauth

I'm new to oauth and api integrations, and am having a hell (can I say that here) of a time trying to figure it out.

I'd like to connect my rails app to Magento (a php ecommerce  cart).

They have some basic docs here:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/authentication/oauth_authentication.html

While I understand the idea of oauth in principle, I have no idea how to implement a custom solution. I've used a few gems (ex: omniauth) to connect to Twitter, and that was fine, but I just don't know how to create my own strategy for connecting to Magento.

Does anyone know how to do it? Is there a walk-through or screencast somewhere I can use?

If not, what tools or approaches might you recommend for me to figure it out -- if only by trial and error?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get this kind of guttural response when I hear the M-word (Magento), having spent several months attempting to make it do anything useful.  But... assuming you have no choice, and assuming Magento offers a standard OAuth server, then you should be able to use OmniAuth to connect to Mag...blurrgh..ento.

Magento will need to provide several tokens, client_id and client_secret.  You use these to request an access token for your app.  Once you have it, you can reuse it semi-permanently.  OmniAuth might be able to help you with that.

Once you have the access token, you'll need to pass an HTTP header that looks like `Authentication: OAuth <access-token>` with every request you make to the service.

Requests are made using standard https (I would hope, vs http) to the server.  Within Rails you could roll your own REST client (using Net::HTTP and friends), but you might find a gem like [RestClient, linked here](https://github.com/archiloque/rest-client).  There are others out there -- check [The Ruby Toolbox for more](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/http_clients).

Does that get you started?

Comment: Google "magento sucks" just fer laughs.

Comment: Yep, that helps. I was trying http, but needed https. Got it going now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here are detailed instructions from the repo of the [omniauth-magento gem / strategy](https://github.com/Zookal/omniauth-magento) I created:

**Setting up Magento**

*Consumer key & secret*

Set up a consumer in Magento and write down consumer key and consumer secret

*Privileges*

In the Magento Admin backend, go to *System > Web Services > REST Roles*, select *Customer*, and tick *Retrieve* under *Customer*. Add more privileges as needed.

*Attributes*

In the Magento Admin backend, go to *System > Web Services > REST Attributes*, select *Customer*, and tick *Email*, *First name* and *Last name* under *Customer > Read*. Add more attributes as needed.

**Setting up Rails**

Parts of these instructions are based on these [OmniAuth instructions](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3a-Overview), which you can read in case you get stuck.

*Devise*

Install [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) if you haven't installed it

Add / replace this line in your *routes.rb*. This will be called once Magento has successfully authorized and returns to the Rails app.

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks"}
```

*Magento oAuth strategy*

Load this library into your Gemfile `gem "omniauth-magento"` and run `bundle install`

Modify *config/initializers/devise.rb*:

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  # deactivate SSL on development environment
  OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER ||= OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE if Rails.env.development? 
  config.omniauth :magento,
    "ENTER_YOUR_MAGENTO_CONSUMER_KEY",
    "ENTER_YOUR_MAGENTO_CONSUMER_SECRET",
    { :client_options => { :site => "ENTER_YOUR_MAGENTO_URL_WITHOUT_TRAILING_SLASH" } }
  # example:
  # config.omniauth :magento, "12a3", "45e6", { :client_options =>  { :site => "http://localhost/magento" } }
```

*Optional*: If you want to use the Admin API (as opposed to the Customer API), you need to overwrite the default authorize_path like so:

```
{ :client_options => { :authorize_path => "/admin/oauth_authorize", :site => ENTER_YOUR_MAGENTO_URL_WITHOUT_TRAILING_SLASH } }
```

In your folder *controllers*, create a subfolder *users*

In that subfolder *app/controllers/users/*, create a file *omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb* with the following code:

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def magento
    # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
    @user = User.find_for_magento_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)

    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "magento") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.magento_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
end
```

*User model & table*

Here's an example of useful Magento information you can store in your User table once you have created these columns:

- email
- first_name
- last_name
- magento_id
- magento_token
- magento_secret

*Optional*: You might want to encrypt *magento_token* and *magento_secret* with the *attr_encrypted gem* for example (requires renaming magento_token to encrypted_magento_token and magento_secret to encrypted_magento_secret).

Set up your *User* model to be `omniauthable :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:magento]` and create a method to save retrieved information after successfully authenticating.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base  
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable,
         :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :timeoutable,
         :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:magento]  

  def self.find_for_magento_oauth(auth, signed_in_resource=nil)
    user = User.find_by(email: auth.info.email)
    if !user
      user = User.create!(
        first_name: auth.info.first_name,                           
        last_name:  auth.info.last_name,
        magento_id: auth.uid,
        magento_token: auth.credentials.token,
        magento_secret: auth.credentials.secret,
        email:      auth.info.email,
        password:   Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
      )
    else
      user.update!(
        magento_id: auth.uid,
        magento_token: auth.credentials.token,
        magento_secret: auth.credentials.secret
      )
    end    
    user
  end         
end
```

*Link to start authentication*

Add this line to your view `<%= link_to "Sign in with Magento", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:magento) %>`

**Authenticating**

Start your Rails server

Start your Magento server

Log into Magento with a customer account (or admin account if you want to use the Admin API)

In your Rails app, go to the view where you pasted this line `<%= link_to "Sign in with Magento", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:magento) %>`

Click on the link

You now should be directed to a Magento view where you are prompted to authorize access to the Magento user account

Once you have confirmed, you should get logged into Rails and redirected to the Rails callback URL specified above. The user should now have magento_id, magento_token and magento_secret stored.

**Making API calls**

Create a class that uses magento_token and magento_secret to do API calls for instance in *lib/magento_inspector.rb*. Example:

```
class MagentoInspector
  require "oauth"
  require "omniauth"
  require "multi_json"

  def initialize
    @access_token = prepare_access_token(current_user) # or pass user in initialize method 
    @response = MultiJson.decode(@access_token.get("/api/rest/customers").body) # or pass query in initialize method, make sure privileges and attributes are enabled for query (see section at top)
  end

private

  # from http://behindtechlines.com/2011/08/using-the-tumblr-api-v2-on-rails-with-omniauth/
  def prepare_access_token(user)
    consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new("ENTER_YOUR_MAGENTO_CONSUMER_KEY", "ENTER_YOUR_MAGENTO_CONSUMER_SECRET", {:site => "ENTER_YOUR_MAGENTO_URL_WITHOUT_TRAILING_SLASH"})
    token_hash = {:oauth_token => user.magento_token, :oauth_token_secret => user.magento_secret}
    access_token = OAuth::AccessToken.from_hash(consumer, token_hash)
  end
end
```

Make sure Rails loads files in the folder where this class is placed. For the lib folder, put this in *config/application.rb*: `config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]`

Perform query `MagentoInspector.new`

Extend class to suit your needs

Comment: is there a way to dynamically set the Magento Site?

Comment: You can use ENV variables if you want it to be dependent on the environment. Is that what you are after?